# Ruby on Rails - Basic Controller Setup on Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dreamhost

I'm working my way through Agile Web Development with Rails and am running into this problem on a shared system (Dreamhost).

```
[******]$ ruby script/generate controller Say
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2 (you have 1.3.1). Please `gem update --system` and try again.
[******]$ gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

The problem is that I am not root (or lack permissions on /usr/lib/....).  How do I solve this?  There must be a configuration file I can set somewhere?/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://baddabigboom.com/articles/2008/05/12/deploying-a-rails-app-to-dreamhost

If you scroll down halfway he explains setting up locally installed gems.

Comment: Can you help me understand this step:
rm -f /PATH/TO/GEM/PATH/FROM/ABOVE/source_cache

I'm not sure which is the source cache from the gem env dump?

Answer (score 0):

What version is your rails app?
Dreamhost is running rails 2.2.2 and rubygems 1.3.1
I have my rails 2.3.2 app pretending to be 2.2.2 as described here [1](http://www.42.mach7x.com/2009/06/16/undefined-method-cache_template_loading-for-actionviewbaseclass). It could be that rails > 2.3.2 may need a newer version of rubygems. Downgrading rails (or making it look like it is 2.2.2) may solve your problem. Just a thought.